# Cypress check if one element has a certain text value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I'm trying to set up my first Cypress tests and I can not find how to see if one of my elements that I get with the `cy.get()` command has a certain value.

Maybe my approach is not correct. This is what I want to do:

I have a form that has two dates. After submitting the form, the backend has some additional validation. Both date forms can't be selected to the same date (for example). If there is an validation error, I want to display this error below the form. This gets displayed with a `span` element (This is at least how Material Ui is doing it).

Now with my test I want to get all `span` elements and see, if one of them has an error message.

How could I implement this?

I tried `cy.get('span').contains('Some error message')` but this seems not to work.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) which will loop through all your span elements and then you can extract the innerText and validate it against your error message.

```
cy.get('span').each(($elm) => {
    cy.wrap($elm).invoke('text').then((text) => {
        if (text == "Error Message") {
            //Do Something
        }
        else {
            //Do Something
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How would I be able to return a test pass int the if-condition?

Comment: you can add an assertion inside if with something like `expect(text).to.equal('Error Message')` or write `return` to come out of if block.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, that will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element%E2%80%99s-text-contents) you can try:

```
cy.get('span').should('have.text', 'Some error message')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea, I had another idea after creating this message. I have added a `data-testId` to my component. Now I can do something like this `cy.get('[error-message] > span').should('have.text', 'Some error message')` and this worked  .
Still thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah also, I tried your suggestion with `contain.text`, this works and passes the test. `have.text` seems not to work.